# Mismatch in filename uploaded to aptly

Tags: debian, repository

When I try to upload a debian with name {service_name}_2.5.0~0_amd64.deb into aptly, I check the file content via the web link of aptly I could see the file being uploaded as {service_name}_2.5.0-0_amd64.deb. I thought its to do with ~, but it doesn't happen always.. is there some issue with aptly regarding ~ versions.

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to expected Debian package naming conventions. The `-0` in `{service_name}_2.5.0-0_amd64.deb` is the [Debian revision number](https://linux.die.net/man/5/deb-version), which can be updated separately from the version of the package itself. See [documentation on Debian package version conventions](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version) and [a discussion on use of tilde in Debian package naming](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230911/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-tilde-in-some-debian-openjdk-package-version-string).